# Move a Data table to clipboard and paste it in excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, clipboard

I'm trying to move data from a data table to excel. Is it possible to copy-paste the data table using a clipboard?

```
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(ds.Tables[0]);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        xlApp.UserControl = true;
        xlApp.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Excel FilePath");
        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[2].Activate();
        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[2].PasteSpecial(Missing.Value, false, false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Is this the correct way of implementing it?

Comment: Try Epplus from NuGet. It has a LoadFromDataTable() method. BTW, you don't need all those "Missing.Value"s

Comment: @CetinBasoz It works fine.
I have created some pivot tables in excel based on the exported data. Is there any way to execute the RefreshAll in excel.

Comment: @KanianNakkeeran if this code worked fine you wouldn't need to use the clipboard. You can't use this code in any kind of server application either, it will leak Excel instances. Use Epplus.

Comment: From Falk: `try xlApp.CalculateFullRebuild()`

Comment: You can [create Pivot tables in Epplus too](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp/Sample12.cs)

Comment: Although as not as flexible as in Excel, you can still create pivot tables in Epplus. If you still want to pass data to Excel via clipboard, then use array (object[,]).

Comment: @CetinBasoz- Thanks for your help. I've used this link to create pivot tables in c# itself, https://techbrij.com/pivot-c-array-datatable-convert-column-to-row-linq.
And exporting it to excel using the Epplus library.

Comment: excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Cells["C8"].Value = RunningTime.ToString();
excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Select();
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("n.pdf");
excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);

I used this code to save the excel as pdf, but it didn't work out with epplus. Is there any option to save as pdf using epplus?

Comment: @CetinBasoz. Epplus always exports the complete file when using 'SaveAs' option.
Is it possible to export only specific sheet?